# Why is C-i executing TAB instead of evil-jump-forward?

Tags: key-bindings

For some reason, pressing ctrl+i is sending a TAB command instead of executing evil-jump-forward. Viewing the lossage, I see:

```
C-o [evil-jump-backward]
TAB [c-indent-line-or-region]
```

From describe-bindings I see:

```
 <C-i>      evil-jump-forward
```

I've even updated my .spacemacs file:

```
  (global-set-key (kbd "C-i") 'evil-jump-forward)
```

..but this has the same result. Any ideas on what could be the issue?

Comment: `C-i` is the ASCII control character `TAB`. If you bind `C-i` to one command and then bind `TAB` to a different command, it's the same as binding `C-i` to first one then the other command. Those are the exact same keys. However the key `<tab>` can be bound to a different command, and that will typically be used when you hit the TAB key.

Comment: This question is probably a duplicate - perhaps someone can locate the original...